# Java return string object

Tags: java, database

I have a database function that retrieves data and then populates a jtable. I need to change this function so it RETURNS the data from the database within an `Object[][]`. How can this be done? (I'm unsure on how to store the data on each row iteration - the while loop part in the code below).

```
public void data() {
    // clear table then load information 
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();  
         model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
  table.repaint(); 
  ResultSet rs=null;
  Statement st=null;

    try { 
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver"); 
        _con = DriverManager.getConnection(_url,_user,_pwd);
        st = _con.createStatement(); 
        String query = "SELECT * FROM table";

        rs = st.executeQuery(query); 

        while (rs.next()) { 
            String d1 = rs.getString("record1"); 
            String d2 = rs.getString("record2");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{d1,d2}); 
        }        
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (_con != null) {
                _con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wher are `_con`, `st`, and `rs` defined?

Comment: Member variables, obviously.  That's a bad idea, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this method is a good idea for several reasons:

1. A method should do one thing well.  You've got UI, connection acquisition, and querying all mingled in this one method.  I'd start breaking them up a bit more.  The persistence layer should not know or care that you're using Swing.
2. Close those resources in individual try/catch blocks in the finally block.  You still want the others to close if one throws an exception.
3. An empty catch block is a terrible idea.  Print or log the stack trace.
4. Create the `Connection` outside this method and pass it in.
5. `ResultSet` and `Statement` should not be member variables of the class.  Make them local to the method.

Just change the method to return what you want instead of `void`.  I wouldn't use an `Object [][]`; I'd prefer a List of Maps or some other type that encapsulated a row.  Use the column names as the keys in the Map.

Answer (score 0):

here's some code OP has asked for, and yes, OP should pay heed to duffymo's recomendations -  I totally agree on them.

```
  Object[] result = null;

  try{ 

   Class.forName("java.sql.Driver"); 
   _con = DriverManager.getConnection(_url,_user,_pwd);
   st=_con.createStatement(); 

   String query="SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table";
   rs=st.executeQuery(query); 
   Integer size = null;
   if (rs.next()){
       size = rs.getInteger("cnt");
   }

   if (size != null){
     Object[] result = new Object[size];
     query="SELECT * FROM table";    
     rs=st.executeQuery(query); 
     int i = 0;
     while(rs.next())
     { 
         String d1=rs.getString("record1"); 
         String d2=rs.getString("record2");
         result[i++] = new Object[]{d1,d2}; 
     }        
   }
   } 
   catch(Exception e)  
   { 
      //TODO handle exceptions, e.g. rethrow 
      //throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
```